# Link colors on overall div

Tags: html, css, anchor

So I have a div where the whole thing is an anchor tag and I am trying to control how the color is on hover and getting varying results. Hoping I can do this with just css. What is happening is on hover, one text changes, but not the other. But then also, the text decoration underline is still different. Just want it all to stay black even on hover, but on hover, the url underline appears on the text.

```
<style>
    .welTile > p:hover {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="#/mod1">
        <div class="welTile">
            <img src="assets/images/welcomeTile.png">
            <p>Module 1: Moneyball Concepts</p>
            <p>Learn the basic concepts you need to successfully complete the other 5 modules</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And a couple of screenshots of what is happening before and after hovering:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the text become lime colored, you have a rule somewhere doing that. We need to see that rule and its specificity, to be able to tell how to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS will keep everything to stay in black.

```
.col-md-4 a, .col-md-4 a:hover, .col-md-4 a:focus, .col-md-4 a:active {
    color: black;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to target the different states of the anchor tag like this:

```
.col-md-4 a {
    color: #000;
}
.col-md-4 a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.col-md-4 a:focus {
    color: #000;
}
.col-md-4 a:active {
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: But I want the text decoration, just want it the same color as the text.

Comment: The `a:hover, a:focus, a:active` doesn't do anything since their specificity is lower than `.col-md-4 a`